# Set[A] from List[A] based on a field of A

Tags: scala

I have a class:

```
class Product {

    val productID = ...
    val weight = ...
    val size = ....

     .....[more fields]....

}
```

I have a List[Product] which contains the same product multiple times. How can I convert the list into a Set[Product] using productID as the 'unique' value so that each Product is only included once?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard way to do it:

```
val a = List(a1, a2...)

val as = a.toSet
```

If you mean that you have products with the same ID, but different, and you would be OK with picking whatever product, then you can do something like that:

```
val a = List(a1, a2...)
val a_ids = a map(_.productId) toSet

val products = a_ids.flatMap(id => a.find(_.productId == id))
```

Comment: thanks, but this does not produce a set of unique Products. I guess that beneath the hood each Product object is unique, however they actually have the same productID

Comment: I got it, see my update